# Is there a way of connecting java midlet to a jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, midlet

I want to connect a midlet to a jsp page. Can i do it directly or should i rewrite the code of the jsp nto a servlet?

Answer (score 0):

A jsp is essentially a servlet. All JSPs compile into servlets, so "connecting" to a jsp is the same as "connecting" to a servlet.

What exactly do you mean by connecting to a servlet? A servlet usually implement doGet(...) and/or doPost(...). If you request an URL via HTTP GET, the doGet()-method is called.

Comment: When connecting to a servlet the doGet and doPost methods are used. And then you are calling the results from the midlet. When i try to do the same thing with the jsp it outputs some html codes as written in the code. Not outputs or anything. I can't understand if i can directly call a jsp page or if i need a servlet to do it.